# CakePHP Support Legacy URL

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a legacy URL which I absolutely have to support, which is in this format:

```
http://domain.com/page.php?hash=crazymd5hashhere
```

The new version of the site is being done in CakePHP 2.4, so I want to redirect this to an actual controller action and pass it the hashed parameter. What's the best way of accomplishing this in CakePHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /controller_name/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the server respond with a permanent redirect `301` code to the new address. This will be cached by browsers, and also tell search engines to drop the old content from their indexes.

The easiest and fastest approach would be to create a `page.php` file in your webroot that issues the redirect.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET["hash"]))
    {
       $location = "/controller/action/hash:"+$_GET["hash"];
       header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
       header ('Location: '.$location);
    }
    else
    {
       header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    }
```

I have no idea where it needs to redirect too, but that was just an example.